# React Native font size differs on Xcode/Simulator vs physical device

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, font-size

I have been having trouble getting my React Native app layout to look the same on a physical iPhone 11 Pro as it does on an iOS simulator of an iPhone 11 Pro. Specifically the issue is with text rendering. It seems like the font size is simply not the same on the two.

Xcode and Simulator are version 11.7, and iOS 13.7 is on both the phone and the simulator. React Native is version 0.61.5.

Since I can't share the entire screen I have cropped to the relevant area. I have left part of the adjacent graphics in to indicate the dimensions of the space.

iPhone 11 Pro simulator rendering:

[image: Simulator]

iPhone 11 Pro device rendering:

[image: iPhone 11 Pro]

RN View:

```
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Image source={require('./assets/tophalf.jpg')}
          style={{width: '100%', height: '50%'}}
          imageStyle={{resizeMode: 'contain'}} />
      <View style={styles.container2}>
      <View style={{flex:1}} />
      <View style={{flex:8}}>
          <View style={{flex:4, alignSelf:'center', width: '85%'}}>
            <Text style={styles.aboutfont}>{loremtext}</Text>
          </View>
          <View style={{flex:2}}>
            <Image source={require('./assets/blob.png')}
                  style={{flex:1, width:'50%', height:'50%', alignSelf: 'flex-end'}}
                  resizeMode="contain" />
          </View>
          <View style={{flex:1}} />
        </View>
      </View>
      <Image source={require('./assets/middlebox.png')}
        style={{position:'absolute', alignItems: 'center',
                width:100, height:100,
                borderWidth:1, borderColor:'#eeeeee', borderRadius:5,
                aspectRatio:1}}
      />
    </View>
```

And the style elements:

```
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#ffffff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
  container2: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: 'white',
    justifyContent: 'space-around',
  },
  aboutfont: {
    fontSize: 14,
    fontFamily: Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 'Futura' : 'Roboto',
    color: 'black',
    textAlign: 'center',
  },
```

Any help would be appreciated. I don't know enough to say if this is a React Native issue specifically or something with Xcode/Simulator.

Comment: Do you know if you have the font size changed on the device or simulator? You can see how to do that [here](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202828). I've had to adjust the size before on my own projects :)

Comment: @FredAstaire Confirmed I have not changed it on the device or the simulator.

Comment: Aaaaaand I'm dumb. See my comment on the accepted answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

my first intuition is that you probably have different settings for text size and/or display zoom on your physical device and your simulator. React Native's Text Component is smart enough to scale with the users' settings, both on iOS and Android.

Try checking the values in Settings > Display & Brightness > Text Size
and in Settings > Display & Brightness > Display Zoom > View

Hope that solves your problem!

Comment: I hadn't thought to check that, but in my case it is not the issue. Mine is set to Standard.

Comment: Augh! I stand corrected -- it was my wife's phone where the issue showed up and she did have the text size set larger. Thanks.

Comment: haha after debugging for the last 3 days. this was the issue.

Comment: So something similar happened to me (changing the Display Zoom > View solved my issue on the simulator).

Answer (score 2):

Thanks a lot @Jaakko that was the case for me as well,

however you can fix that by setting the property of the text

```
<Text .... allowFontScaling ={false}></Text>
```

to keep its size standard

or

```
<Text .... maxFontSizeMultiplier={number} minimumFontScale={number} ></Text>
```

to only allow certain range of scaling that doesn't break your design.

Happy Coding To All.